# Smash Up Question about Werewolves

Tags: smash-up

LET THE DOG OUT

> Destroy any number of minions at your minion's base whose total power is less than or equal to your minion's power.

Is this referring to the total power of **all** minions that are to be destroyed or is it referring to the total power of **each** individual minion to be destroyed?

If my minion is worth 6, does that mean I can destroy all minions who have power of 6 or less? Or am I only able to destroy a grand total of 6, such as a 4-minion plus a 2-minion?

Answer (score 10):

The total power of a set of minions is the sum of their powers.

If your minion has a power of 6, you could destroy a minion of power 4 and a minion of power 2, but you could not destroy a minion of power 4 and a minion of power 3.

To get the other meaning, it would be phrased the same except for the removal of the word "total".